# Removed both Linux installations, but BIOS still shows them in boot options

Tags: boot, windows, dual-boot

I dual booted Linux mint with earlier installed Windows 10 on my HP Pavilion 15 by selecting option something else in installation and then creating two ext4 drives for root and home.

Recently I wanted to try kali Linux, so I started installing it and in configure partition option I deleted root of Linux mint and then created new root partition from free space formed and used earlier home partition as home again.

When I pressed F9 for boot options it still showed Linux mint option.

As kali wasn't working well it constantly hanged and crashed so in disk management of windows I deleted both root and home partition.

Now the boot options shows boot kali and Linux mint. and on opening them they enter into grub rescue and grub respectively.

What should I do to remove these options I had tried boot repair of ubuntu and fixmbr also.

Comment: UEFI (BIOS) might remember those systems being there, it would be a good start to visit your UEFI boot settings and take a picture.

Comment: How to get into your UEFI (BIOS) may vary: https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c00034791

Comment: If you are solely on Windows now, which your current question seems to point towards to, please say that - [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/552728/edit) please, so that the moderators could help you move it to a different StackExchange site (https://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 6):

If you don't have a Linux Live CD available, you can remove the entries within Windows too.

First, open a Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`) *as an Administrator.*

Then, use `bcdedit /enum firmware` to view a list of boot options from the firmware menu. Each entry will have multiple items, like `identifier`, `device`, `description` etc. The value of the `description` fields should match what you see in the F9 boot options.

To delete an entry, use `bcdedit /delete <identifier>`, replacing `<identifier>` with the identifier GUID value of the corresponding entry. So the command should look like this:

```
bcdedit /delete {12345678-9abc-def0-1234-56789abcdef0}
```

Comment: Are we answering Windows questions now? Sorry, but if the OP or you for that matter insist on a Windows solution, this whole thing must be flagged for it would belong to SuperUser. I've not persuaded myself at this point to do that myself, yet anyway... You can flag it yourself, other than that I find no other problem here. Yet you did answer a (seemingly) Windows matter in a Windows way.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak I considered it as a "last thing in those Linux installations' lifecycles". Strictly speaking, if there was an "UEFI StackExchange", that would be the place it would belong to... but personally I accept a bit of overlap at the edge cases like this, in the interest of preferring to build bridges rather than walls.

Comment: Ah, was I a bit hostile? Probably, sorry about that. I did not realize it until now upon reading my comment again. I agree we should probably put our forces together to build a glorious common ground for every question being well-documented and the new-comers not feeling here like *strangers*, but all that will not change the fact the OP does not communicate at all since he posted and you answered his here on Unix *invalid* question with a perfectly valid answer, *on SuperUser*, that is. What more to say? I will flag it for possible migration now. Thank you for your time and effort!

Comment: I was looking for this for so long. The GUI BCD apps don't work on EFI. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

If you can't delete the entries directly from the UEFI firmware, boot with a linux live CD and run [`efibootmgr`](https://manpages.debian.org/efibootmgr/efibootmgr.8#EXAMPLES) to remove the entries.

> EXAMPLES
>
> 1.
>
> DISPLAYING THE CURRENT SETTINGS (MUST BE ROOT).
>
> ```
> [root@localhost ~]# efibootmgr
> BootCurrent: 0004
> BootNext: 0003
> BootOrder: 0004,0000,0001,0002,0003
> Timeout: 30 seconds
> Boot0000* Diskette Drive(device:0)
> Boot0001* CD-ROM Drive(device:FF) 
> Boot0002* Hard Drive(Device:80)/HD(Part1,Sig00112233)   
> Boot0003* PXE Boot: MAC(00D0B7C15D91)               
> Boot0004* Linux
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> 5.
>
> DELETING A BOOT OPTION
>   Assuming the configuration in Example #1, `efibootmgr -b 4 -B` could be called to delete entry 4 and remove it from the BootOrder.

You should also remove left over GRUB files in the EFI partition.